# Long term Behavior of Dynamical System

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-analysis

Given the following dynamical system:

$ \dot x = -6x^2+yz+x-1 $

$ \dot y = 4xz-3y^2+y-2 $

$ \dot z = 9xy-2z^2+z-3 $

What can you say about its long term behavior?

Attempt:

First, finding the fixed points.

There is only one real solution to $x'=0$, $y'=0$ and $z'=0$ and this is at the point $(1,2,3)$.  At this point, the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are 
$\lambda = 1,-17  $  Because of the positive eigenvalue, this fixed point is unstable.

I have also run into fixed points for the above system but they are complex.  Do these complex fixed points have an influence on the dynamics of the system?

Comment: 1) No, complex ($\mathbb{C}$) solutions of equation for finding equilibria don't influence real ($\mathbb{R}$) dynamics. At least it's true in the sense that these complex-valued equilibria don't give rise to other real-valued equilibria. 2) How (and where) did you get this system? It might be important because this could hint whether this system has some nice properties (integrals, symmetries, etc. ).

Comment: It was given to me by a colleague. I do not know the context of where the system came from.

Comment: That's definitely makes it harder to analyze. At least the first thing that you can do is to make a coordinate system shift to place equilibrium at the origin of new coordinate system (equations might become a bit simpler).

Comment: So after applying X=x-1, Y=y-2,Z=z-3, the new ODE under this coordinate shift is X'=YZ+3Y+2Z-6X^2-11X, Y'=4XZ+4Z+12X-3Y^2-11Y, and Z'=9XY+18X+9Y-2Z^2-11Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variables $x \to \xi$, $y \to 2 \eta$, $z \to 3 \zeta$ yields the system
\begin{align}
 \dot{\xi} &= f(\xi) + 6 \eta \zeta, \\
 \dot{\eta} &= f(\eta) + 6 \xi \zeta, \tag{1}\\
 \dot{\zeta} &= f(\zeta) + 6 \xi \eta, 
\end{align}
with
\begin{equation}
 f(x) = -6 x^2 +x-1.
\end{equation}
Not only is the vector field of $(1)$ conservative (its curl vanishes), it is also invariant under all permutations of the triple $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$.

This type of systems has been studied extensively by Martin Golubitsky. A good source is

M. Golubitsky, I. Stewart, *The Symmetry Perspective*, Birkhäuser, Basel, 2002.

Of particular interest is section 3.4 in chapter 3, on rings of cells.

**Addition:** The symmetry suggests another coordinate change. Note that the linear combination $\xi+\eta+\zeta$ is invariant under permutations of $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$. Therefore, introducing the (suitably normalised) coordinates
\begin{align}
 X &= \frac{\xi - \eta}{\sqrt{2}},\\
 Y &= \frac{\xi+\eta - 2 \zeta}{\sqrt{6}},\\
 Z &= \frac{\xi+\eta+\zeta}{\sqrt{3}},
\end{align}
yields
\begin{align}
 \dot{X} &= X(1 - 6 \sqrt{3} Z),\\
 \dot{Y} &= Y(1 - 6 \sqrt{3} Z),\\
 \dot{Z} &= Z-\sqrt{3} - 3 \sqrt{3}(X^2+Y^2).
\end{align}
The equation for $Z$ suggests the introduction of polar coordinates $X = R \cos \theta$, $Y = R \sin \theta$, yielding
\begin{align}
 \dot{R} &= R(1 - 6 \sqrt{3} Z),\\
 \dot{\theta} &= 0\\
 \dot{Z} &= Z-\sqrt{3} - 3 \sqrt{3}R^2.
\end{align}
So, the three-dimensional system is reduced to a planar system.

Comment: This is amazing, sir :) What made you think about this change of variables, constant terms? P.S. Too bad that books of Golubitsky, Field and Stewart aren't that easy to find...

Comment: Thanks! Well, it was all a bit of stumbling around, but I first saw that neither div or curl of the original vector field vanished. Then I tried to make one of those vanish by a rescaling of the variables, which worked, and produced this amazingly symmetric system. I plotted a level curve of the potential function in Mathematica, which clearly showed a) a certain rotational invariance, and b) a dominant direction (axis of rotation), which was (1,1,1). And no, unfortunately, those books are hard to come by.

Comment: An interesting approach, thank you for the explanation!